# Acces to Sugar & Sweeteners USDA reports

Tags: data.gov

I work with investments related to commodities and I would like to have access to the following report:

"LMC International: Sugar and Sweeteners Market Report"

Could you help me to get access to that?

Comment: what have you done to access this data? there seem to be annual versions of this, what year are you requesting? we need more information from you.

Answer (score 1):

According to Data.gov, the accessLevel of the [2018 LMC International: Sugar and Sweeteners Market Report](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/lmc-international-sugar-and-sweeteners-market-reportdata) is **non-public**.

> This field refers to the degree to which this dataset could be made available to the public, regardless of whether it is currently available to the public. For example, if a member of the public can walk into your agency and obtain a dataset, that entry is public even if there are no files online. A restricted public dataset is one only available under certain conditions or to certain audiences (such as researchers who sign a waiver). **A non-public dataset is one that could never be made available to the public** for privacy, security, or other reasons as determined by your agency.

-quote from [Project Open Data accessLevel field usage notes](https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema/#accessLevel) (emphasis added)

That sounds like a definitive "No" to me. The only room for negotiation I see, is if you're not part of "the public."

Have you tried emailing the contact person listed on the data.gov page for this dataset (linked above)? What did they say?

Comment: IANAL, but it sounds like anyone who did provide this data set to you, might be committing a serious crime. But that's a question for law.SE.